# Parsing a document , C

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I need to parse a document in C language.  I was about to use the strtok function but I don't know if it's the best method or if just a token system is enough (searching for \n, space etc).

The structure of each line of the document is : element \n element "x".

thanks :-)

Comment: You definition of line is a bit inconsistent with C's usual definition of line: "a bunch of characters terminated by (and including) a `'\n'`". You're going to have to do extra work to deal with the embedded `'\n'` in your "line".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token system if fine, `strtok` is just an implementation of that. However, you're better off with using [`strtok_r`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtok/) which does not keep any internal state outside control of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the details, but I saw in several sources that strtok was an unsafe piece of work. You'd be better off rolling your own, if you ask me.

Comment: `strtok()` is not reentrant. However, you can use `strtok_r()` which is fine.

Comment: `strtok()` is perfectly fine if your program isn't using shared-memory threads.